# jQuery conflict 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: jquery

Hello, I’ve written a script for autocomplete like Facebook; it works well on a single php page where a single jQuery version is loaded.

I’m forced to use it in a page where there are two jQuery calls:  one to jquery-1.6.min.js and another to: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js

In that case I have a problem and the JavaScript using jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js is not working.

I tried using 
`jQuery.noConflict();`

but in that case the script using jquery-1.6.min.js is not working.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try to avoid using 2 version of jQuery on the same page if possible.

If for some reason you cannot avoid it then you have to use `noConflict` on both the versions of jQuery to maintain both the versions.

Something like var `$1 = jQuery.noConflict()` and var `$2 = jQuery.noConflict()` and use these 2 different variables. Now it is very important to execute the first noConflict code before loading the second jQuery file.

Comment: Your suggestion to use `noConflict` "on both versions" doesn't make much sense since both bind to the same variable name `jQuery` in the same scope. Removing (or conditionally loading) one of the instances is the only solution.

Comment: Something like `var $1 = jQuery.noConflict()` and `var $2 = jQuery.noConflict()` and use these 2 different variables. Now it is very important to execute the first noConflict code before loading the second jQuery file.

Comment: Again: `noConflict()` makes jQuery not bind to `$`. It still binds to `jQuery`, though.

Comment: Yes, thats correct `$` or `jQuery` is moved to `$1`. When second `jQuery` file is loaded, `jQuery` gets overwritten and then we can use `noConflict` to get jQuery into `$2`.

Comment: Errr. My pardon. Actually, use of the `jQuery` variable *can* be prevented by using `noConflict(true)`. Learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: @ShankarSangoli For the sake of completeness, put your comment in the answer. I was going to do it but it's not fair that I get credit for copy-pasting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `script` tag loading your jQuery 1.6 by the following:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "/path/to/jquery-1.6.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

This ensures that your local copy of jQuery is only loaded if no other version (such as the 1.7 from the CDN) exists.